# How to create an Outlook appointment with recurring week days with pywin32?

Tags: vba, outlook, pywin32

I am trying to create a create an Outlook appointment with recurring week days. For example, Tuesdays and Fridays at some time. I looked at the [VBA code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.recurrencepattern.dayofweekmask) to do this and if you look at the line in question, they use what I believe to be an operator?

> .DayOfWeekMask = olMonday Or olWednesday Or olFriday

I'm not entirely sure if it's an operator because the O is capitalized and I cant find any information on this. What is the python equivalent for this? Below is my code.

```
import win32com.client as win32

def create_event(subject, start_time, duration, location, body, recurring=False):
    ol_app = win32.Dispatch('Outlook.Application')
    event_item = ol_app.CreateItem(1) # Appointment item
    event_item.Subject = subject
    event_item.Start = start_time
    event_item.Duration = duration
    event_item.Location = location
    event_item.Body = body
    if recurring == True:
        recurring_pattern = event_item.GetRecurrencePattern()
        recurring_pattern.RecurrenceType = 1 # Weekly
        recurring_pattern.PatternStartDate = '1/20/2022'
        recurring_pattern.PatternEndDate = '5/2/2022'
        recurring_pattern.DayOfWeekMask = 4 # OlDaysOfWeek enumeration for Tuesday.
    event_item.Save()
```

Comment: Related: https://nolongerset.com/how-to-construct-a-bit-mask-in-vba/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [RecurrencePattern.DayOfWeekMask](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.recurrencepattern.dayofweekmask) property returns or sets an [OlDaysOfWeek](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.oldaysofweek) constant representing the mask for the days of the week on which the recurring appointment or task occurs. The equivalent of the following line:

```
.DayOfWeekMask = olMonday Or olWednesday Or olFriday
```

would be the following bitwise or operation:

```
.DayOfWeekMask = olMonday | olWednesday | olFriday
```

See [Bitwise Operators in Python](https://realpython.com/python-bitwise-operators/) for more information.